# Software for creating simple animations in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm trying to add few animations to my game. I searched a bit for some animations software but everything I found was too complicated for me. Is there any simple animation software which I can use with Unity or should I just stick to default Unity animation tool?

Comment: By "Animation" what do you exactly mean? Are you trying 2D or 3D animation, or just tweening properties? (like moving a GameObject). Some details would help.

Comment: I want to animate 3d object. To be exact it is a cube and I want it to roll, but I might use this software for different stuff.

Comment: Try some tweening libraries. DoTween (http://dotween.demigiant.com/) & iTween are rather popular (http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to roll it as you said, you can accomplish this in several ways without exiting Unity.

For instance, here are some :

- Using an Animator component in the cube and applying a premade Animation (made within Unity via Animation window, just change transform rotation properties)
- Using Physics to apply a constant rotation force (torque)
- Using scripting to modify transform rotation properties on each frame update (c# or javascript)

Probably more exist but those are the simplest and easiest.

If I were to choose one, Animator + Animations would be my choice. Also have in mind that this component (Animator) is much better performance wise than any other solution when used on several instances in the scene (lots of cubes).